# Preference when setting and adding an item at the some position in an arraylist

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I guess what I'm essentially asking is the difference between the order of these two operations on an ArrayList.

Suppose you have the following arraylists

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("Tom");
list.add("Jerry");
list.add(1,"Harry");
list.set(1,"Klaus");
System.out.println(list);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[Tom, Klaus, Jerry]
```

Then do the same thing for `list2`except switch the last two statements

```
list2.add("Tom");
list2.add("Jerry");
list2.set(1,"Harry");
list2.add(1,"Klaus");
System.out.println(list2);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[Tom, Klaus, Harry]
```

When the value was `set`at some `posiotion`why does the `list` `add`an item at `position+1` when you attempt to `add` a new item at `position`as in second `list`. Shouldn't `list2` be?

```
[Tom, Klaus]
```

And shouldn't `list`have

```
[Tom, Klaus]
```

Answer (score 3):

Its very simple

`add` inserts a new value at given index

and

`set` replace the value at given index.

---

Have a look at the output after each statement.

```
list.add("Tom");      // Tom
list.add("Jerry");    // Tom, Jerry
list.add(1,"Harry");  // Tom, Harry, Jerry
list.set(1,"Klaus");  // Tom, Klaus, Jerry


list2.add("Tom");      // Tom
list2.add("Jerry");    // Tom, Jerry
list2.set(1,"Harry");  // Tom, Harry
list2.add(1,"Klaus");  // Tom, Klaus, Harry
```

I hope, you got it now.

Answer (score 1):

add: Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.

set: Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element.